# Spring application log duplicate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, logging

I am kinda have a silly question here. I am building a spring hibernate based web application. When I run a test, the log seems to show double. But not all. It looks like below.

```
2017-09-08 10:27:47,443  INFO [main] (PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:177) -   Loading properties file from class path resource [application.properties]
2017-09-08 10:27:48,249  INFO [main] (EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.java:100) - Initializing EHCache CacheManager
2017-09-08 10:27:49,397  INFO [main] (EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.java:100) - Initializing EHCache CacheManager
2017-09-08 10:27:49,421 DEBUG [main] (EhCacheFactoryBean.java:329) -    Creating new EHCache cache region 'aclCache'
2017-09-08 10:28:00,643  INFO [main] (TransactionFactoryFactory.java:62) -  Transaction strategy: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory
2017-09-08 10:28:00,643  INFO [main] (TransactionFactoryFactory.java:62) -  Transaction strategy: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory
2017-09-08 10:28:00,644  INFO [main] (TransactionManagerLookupFactory.java:80) -    No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
2017-09-08 10:28:00,644  INFO [main] (TransactionManagerLookupFactory.java:80) -    No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
2017-09-08 10:28:09,697 DEBUG [main] (AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.java:106) -    Adding transactional method 'count' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
2017-09-08 10:28:10,240 DEBUG [main] (AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.java:106) -    Adding transactional method 'loadUserByUsername' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2017-09-08 10:28:10,378 DEBUG [main] (AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.java:106) -    Adding transactional method 'checkPermission' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2017-09-08 10:28:11,618 DEBUG [main] (JDBCTransaction.java:82) -    begin
2017-09-08 10:28:11,618 DEBUG [main] (JDBCTransaction.java:82) -    begin
2017-09-08 10:28:11,619 DEBUG [main] (JDBCTransaction.java:87) -    current autocommit status: false
2017-09-08 10:28:11,619 DEBUG [main] (JDBCTransaction.java:87) -    current autocommit status: false
```

If you look at the `PropertiesLoaderSupport`, it shows only once. But the others are duplicated. Is it normal or I miss something?

This is my log4j configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"  ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %5p [%t] (%F:%L) -\t%m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework.cache" additivity="false">
        <level value="trace"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework.transaction" additivity="false">
        <level value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework.batch" additivity="false">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="net.ttddyy.dsproxy.listener">
        <level value="debug"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="warn"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.event.internal">
        <level value="info"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.transaction">
        <level value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.cache">
        <level value="warn"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="javax.transaction">
        <level value="all"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.commons.dbcp" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.google" additivity="false">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.activiti" additivity="false">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>
    <root>
        <level value="ERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Below is my pom.xml

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.brutal</groupId>
<artifactId>bizza</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>

<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
    <hibernate.version>3.2.7.ga</hibernate.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <springframework.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <spring-security.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    <spring-security-cas.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring-security-cas.version>
    <spring-integration.version>3.0.7.RELEASE</spring-integration.version>
    <spring-batch.version>2.1.8.RELEASE</spring-batch.version>
    <oracle.version>11.2.0.3</oracle.version>
    <oracle.ucp.version>11.2.0.3</oracle.ucp.version>
    <activiti.version>5.6</activiti.version>
    <cxf.version>2.2.12</cxf.version>
    <jackrabbit.version>1.5.3</jackrabbit.version>
    <xdocreport-mailmerge.version>1.0</xdocreport-mailmerge.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.ttddyy</groupId>
        <artifactId>datasource-proxy</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.uuid</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-uuid-generator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1B</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-cas-client</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security-cas.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-batch.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-batch.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-integration.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-event</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-integration.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-integration.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-integration.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.SP1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
                <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-chain</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-chain</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>${oracle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
        <version>${oracle.ucp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
        <version>2.0b5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${activiti.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>juel</groupId>
                <artifactId>juel</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.odysseus.juel</groupId>
        <artifactId>juel-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- JACKRABBIT -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>se-jcr</artifactId>
        <version>0.9</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackrabbit-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackrabbit-ocm</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- WEBSERVICE AND REST -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-jexl</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-jexl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.8-beta4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpg-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.47</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.47</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>bizza</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                        <Implementation-Build-Time>${timestamp}</Implementation-Build-Time>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.10</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>
                        jar-with-dependencies
                    </descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/BizzaManagerTest.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <doclet>org.jboss.apiviz.APIviz</doclet>
                <docletArtifact>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.apiviz</groupId>
                    <artifactId>apiviz</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.2.GA</version>
                </docletArtifact>
                <useStandardDocletOptions>true</useStandardDocletOptions>
                <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <docencoding>UTF-8</docencoding>
                <breakiterator>true</breakiterator>
                <version>true</version>
                <author>true</author>
                <keywords>true</keywords>
                <additionalparam>
                    -sourceclasspath ${project.build.outputDirectory}
                </additionalparam>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>MavenCentral</id>
        <name>Maven repository</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>codelds</id>
        <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>ibiblio.mirrors</id>
        <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven repo</id>
        <url>http://mvnrepository.com/artifact</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jahia</id>
        <url>http://maven.jahia.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>java-net</id>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/1</url>
        <layout>legacy</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>springsource-release</id>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>se-jcr-repo</id>
        <name>se-jcr-repo</name>
        <url>https://src.springframework.org/svn/se-jcr/repo</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>alfresco</id>
        <url>http://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/activiti</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>t3rdpaty</id>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Can you show your libs in your project? maybe you have multiple libs like apache commons log, log4j for something else.

Comment: @LipingHuang I editted my question. I put the pom file

Comment: Can you add which servlet/controller method, service, DAO layers associated with this log generation?

Comment: You don't happen to have the same job running concurrently that is generating the same output but potentially from different threads of execution do you?

Comment: Nope. I'm running a test using spring transactional junit. I'll put the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the **additivity** attribute is the problem. When I set to false, log only appear once.